# google script reject spreadsheet submit

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function in a spreadsheet based script that is triggered when a submission is made with the spreadsheet form :

```
function onEntry(e){
  Logger.log(e);
  MailApp.sendEmail("scriptadmin@uniben.edu", "New Mail Request", "Someone submited data");
}
```

How can I reject the entry, say if it's a duplicate entry ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [documentation on events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) you will have to choose what data you want check (user name, specific field...) and compare that to data already in the spreadsheet.

You should do these iterations on an array level since it will be far more efficient and fast, you can get data in an array using something like

`var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key).getDataRange().getValues();`

You could also use javascript function like indexOf() that will return -1 if no match if found  or item position in the array if a match is found.

Actually there are many ways to do that but your question is too vague to know what will be the best...

***EDIT :*** following your comment, I'd suggest you let the duplicate form data come into the sheet and then use a script to remove duplicates. You could run this script on a `on form submit trigger` or on a timer to let it run daily or hourly, and send the email only if  the last entry was a new one (no duplicates found)... depending on your use case.
There is [a script in the gallery](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates) that does the job pretty well, it was written by **Romain Vialard**, a GAS TC that has contributed a lot. (the link above goes to the script description but you can get it also in the public gallery, just search for 'remove duplicates' you'll see that other scripts do that, all the scripts in the gallery have been checked by the GAS team)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but am actually interested in rejecting the entry if I find that it will duplicate another one in the spreadsheet. Most event handlers can cancle the action with something like event.preventDefault(), or event.setCancled(), by returning false from the handler. How do I prevent the entry from entering the spreadsheet if I decide that it's a duplicate. Thanks again.

Comment: It turns out that the solution is to delete the entry (it will be the last entry) if it duplicates an existing one. It is also recommended to do it within a lock (LockService)

Answer (score 0):

4 months late, but better late than never.  I believe this function does almost what was originally requested.  i.e. "How do I prevent the entry from entering the spreadsheet if I decide that it's a duplicate."  It is not precisely what was requested, but very close.

This code checks one column against that same column in another sheet, for all rows in that sheet.  Lets say you have a list of companies or clients on a sheet.  That list includes name, phone, address, etc. etc.  Lets say you want to check against the phone number - if the phone number you are currently entering is already on your client sheet, then don't allow entry - or more precisely clear it out immediately upon entering it.

I'm sure the more experienced members will be able to point out flaws, but it works for me.
I believe it will also work for the case where a phone number in the middle of the sheet is changed - so it's not just last line that gets checked, it's the line that gets edited that gets checked - I've not tested this particlar scenario.  Also, I made some changes to variable names to protect the innocent...hopefully I didn't mess anything up while doing that.

I call this function from within another function that is triggered by onEdit. Theoretically it should be able to be installed as an onEdit trigger itself.  I hope someone finds it useful.

```
function checkNewEntryForDuplicate(e) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var entrySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var clientSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients");  
      var r = entrySheet.getActiveCell();
      var lastCol = entrySheet.getLastColumn();

      // If this had any consistency, we'd be able to get the row from entrySheet the same
      // as we get column.  But there is no getRow() method at the sheet level.

      var rowNum = r.getRow(); 

      var clientData=clientSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var phoneColumnOffset=getPhoneColumnOffset(); // You'll need to get the offset elsewhere.  I have a function that does that.
      var columnNum=e.range.getColumn();  // column that is currently being edited

      if (columnNum != phoneColumnOffset+1)   // no point in doing anything else if it's not the column we're interested in.
        return 0;

      var entryRow=entrySheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, lastCol);              
      var phoneNum = e.range.getValue();

      // iterate over each row in the clientData 2-dimensional array. 
      for(i in clientData){
        var row = clientData[i];
        var duplicate = false;

      // For each row this conditional statement will find duplicates

          if(row[phoneColumnOffset] == phoneNum){
            duplicate = true;
            var msg="Duplicate Detected.  Please do not enter.  Deleting it..."
            Browser.msgBox(msg);
            entryRow.clearContent();
            entryRow.clearComment();
            return duplicate;
          }
      }
    return duplicate;  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same things but having no scripts at all and just by spreadsheet functions. That kind of things are just like SQL for me and very interest to do.

For your question, this link will help: http://www.labnol.org/software/find-remove-duplicate-records-google-docs/5169/

Comment: While the link you posted may address the question asked, consider the usefulness of your answer where the link becomes broken. You should add the relevant information from that site to your answer and credit the site using the link posted above.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me but I am not allowed to reproduce contents which related to that site, because the site owner has kept some copyrights for the contents. You can see the line placed on the bottom of that site which is saying "The content is copyrighted to Amit Agarwal and may not be reproduced on other websites." So I am sorry for that.

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't see that hidden away down there. While the copyright means that you cannot copy and paste the content (which you shouldn't do anyway), it doesn't prohibit you from writing a summary of how the problem is solved ;)

Comment: BTW the thing I suggest to do using spreadsheet functions only useful when the contents of the sheet is not huge. Because those functions are not speed as javascript functions. So for sheets that contain huge contents recommended to use javascript function. But I think these kind of sheets will not use to contain huge data and there may be people clever in spreadsheet functioning but not clever in javascripts. That's why I suggest it.